# Annotation grouping in a queryset

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-queryset

```
order_list = Order.objects.filter(
            is_deleted=0, order_status__in=[4], order_type=0)
order_list_data = order_list.annotate(
            customer_gross_sum=F('invoice__original_amount') -
            F('invoice__discount_amount')+F('invoice__tax_amount'),
            dcount=Count('user_id'),customer_transactions=F('invoice__transaction_invoice__transaction_amount'))
print(order_list_data.values())
```

[image]

from the table above, the customer_transactions in the queryset is called in the column payment in the table. The second and third in the table is of the same bill with two transactions. Is it possible to bring that under one data.

TEMPLATE

```
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <td class="no-sort">Sl No</td>
    <td class="no-sort">BILL DATE</td>
    <td class="no-sort">BILL NO</td>
    <td>BILL VALUE (Rs)</td>
    <td>PAYMENT (Rs)</td>
    <td>BALANCE (Rs)</td>
  </thead>
  {% for data in order_list_data %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
    <td>{{data.invoice.bill_date}}</td>
    <td>{{data.invoice.bill_no}}</td>
    <td>{{data.customer_gross_sum}}</td>
    <td>{{data.customer_transactions}}</td>

    <td></td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Expecting an output like [image]

Comment: Can you show template, please.

Comment: Please check now. i have edited

Comment: could probably make a dict of bills by looping through the annotated queryset and adding the sums together if the transactions are from same bill, then pass the dict to the template